# Let $L: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear operator such that $L((1,2)^T)=(-2,3)^T$ and $L((1,-1)^T)=(5,2)^T$, then find $L((7,5)^T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$  be a linear operator. If $L((1,2)^T)=(-2,3)^T$ and $L((1,-1)^T)=(5,2)^T$, find the value of $L((7,5)^T).$

Is there a way to solve these kinds of problems? I only know if $L(\alpha v_1+\beta v_2)=\alpha L(v_1)+\beta L(v_2)$, then the vector space is said to be a linear transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your transformation matrix $L=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$. Then $L((1,2)^T)=(-2,3)^T$ and  $L((1,-1)^T)=(5,2)^T$ give $$\begin{align}&a+2b=-2  &c+2d=3\\&a-b=5 &c-b=2.\end{align}$$ Solving we get $L=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{8}{3}&\dfrac{-7}{3}\\\dfrac{7}{3}&\dfrac{1}{3}\end{bmatrix}$. $\:$So $L((7,5)^T)=\begin{bmatrix}7\\18\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks! But why let the transformation matrix L=(a b c d). Doesn't R2 mean the row or column vectors whose has 2 dimensions? I thought R2 means R 2×1(2 rows,1 column)

Comment: @ShadowZ: If we have a linear transformation from $R^n$ ton $R^m$, the corresponding matrix associated with the transformation will have dimension $m\times n$

Comment: Okay!Thank you!

Comment: Okay!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Right, so you have to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with
$$ \alpha(1,2)+\beta(1,-1)=(7,5)$$

Comment: I figured α equals 4 and β equals 3, then I write L(7,5)^T=4*(-2,3)^T+3*(5,2)^T and I get the answer is (7,18)^T, is it correct?